# como mostrar la carga de un loading antes del html

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

buen dia a todos, bueno para entender a mi pregunta, lo que necesito es cuando le de un **refresh o F5**

[image: quiero que cuando aparesca esto se muestre mi loading primero]

me muestre la animacion de loading.

ya que en mi html creo unas tablas de una consulta
[image: cuando se este consultando me muestre el loading]
pero necesito que mi loading se cargue primero

alguna recomendación que me pudieran dar les agradecería ante mano

AGREGO CODIGO:

ESTRUCTUCTURA DE MI LOADING ANIMADO EN CSS
LO CREO EN EL DOCUMENTO LAODING.PHP

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url ?>assets/css/estilo_loading.css">
<div id="cargarpagina">
        <div class="fondopantalla">
                <div class="centrar">
                <div>
                <h1 class="color1 text-center">Cargando</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="bordeprogress">
                <div class="bodercaja">
                    <div class="cargarporgress">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>  
    </div>
    <script src="<?=base_url?>assets/js/loading.js"></script>
```

js LOADINGJS

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#cargarpagina").fadeOut(1200);
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".mostrar").fadeIn(1200);
}, 500);
```

EN ESTE CODIGO HAGO QUE EL Preloader APAERSCA EN UN TIEMPO Y DESPUES SE OCULTE.

Y HAGO UN INCLUDE_ONCE EN MI HEADER.PHP PARA HACER QUE SE CARGUE PRIMERO

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.79.0">
     <link href="<?=base_url?>assets/img/logoLcc.png" rel="icon">
    <title>REPORTEADOR</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url?>assets/css/estilos_header.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url?>assets/bootstrap/css/daterangepicker.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url?>assets/sweetalert/sweetalert2.min.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<?php include_once 'base_url?>assets/js/home.js'?>
</head>
<body>
```

LO QUE NECESITO ES QUE ME RECARGUE PRIMERO EL LOAGING Y DESPUES LO DEMAS DE MI CODIGO

Comment: ¿Tienes algo de código hecho para que podamos ver por donde enfocas el problema?

Comment: @JackMore si claro dejame editarlo

Comment: @JackMore ya hice la editacion

Comment: @josedejesus debes aceptar la respuesta que más te pudo haber ayudado y solucionado. Marca con ✓ para haceptar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega este div a tu código html

```
<div class="loader_bg">
         <div class="loader"><img src="Aqui Url del Gif que quieres mostrar" alt="#" /></div>
      </div>
```

Agrega este atributo y valor a la etiqueta de Body

```
onload="loaded();"
```

Por ultimo integra este código Js a tu codigo html

```
<script>
function loaded() {
"use strict";
                    
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.loader_bg').fadeToggle();
  }, 1500);
                
}
</script>
```

Por ultimo los parametros de estilo css

```
.loader_bg {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999999;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.loader {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.loader img {
    width: 280px;
}
```

Espero que te sirva Saludos

Comment: gracias por sus respuestas me funcionaron

Comment: me da gusto me vi en la misma situación

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto una idea muy buena de como implementar un efecto de carga muy fácil.

Si no es una buena respuesta (porque falta tu estilo CSS), es un buen ejemplo de como implementar, en este caso usando jQuery.

Establezco el div del efecto de carga normalmente visible y absolutamente sobre todo los demás contenidos.

Cuando la pagina carga todos los contenidos, uso `ready()` de `jQuery` para sacar el div del efecto.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Inmediatamente
        //$("#cargarpagina").hide()
        
        // Se espera un tiempo
        setTimeout( function() {
            $("#cargarpagina").fadeOut(1200)
        },500)
    })
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}html,body{margin:0;padding:0}
    
    #cargarpagina {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9999;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 100px;
        color: yellow;
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)
    }

    header,main,footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: justify;
        padding: 0 5rem
    } header,footer {
        height: 100px;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #ccc
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="cargarpagina">
    <span>Cargando...</span>
</div>

<header>
    <div>HEADER</div>
</header>

<main>
    <h1>CONTENIDO</h1>
    <P>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio quaerat repellendus assumenda, voluptate ad maiores nam aliquam quod corporis delectus quam adipisci esse illum nulla, ducimus aperiam laborum explicabo ut ea velit, vel modi temporibus natus ipsam. Sed, alias recusandae a praesentium inventore quaerat accusantium impedit dolores neque, assumenda dolorem accusamus, unde eligendi. Atque maiores autem facere aut quod dolor consequatur accusamus suscipit ratione impedit veritatis, similique nobis doloremque totam, earum a dolore ipsa deserunt. Asperiores, odio facere enim quidem dicta obcaecati nostrum. Rerum iure ducimus officia. Consectetur, explicabo dolore? Consectetur architecto voluptates quasi quis, ea error aliquid eos rem esse sapiente aspernatur. Quod quaerat quo voluptas culpa eum, consequatur optio perferendis quasi repellendus nulla sint magnam nobis laborum recusandae quia obcaecati distinctio dolores amet quidem. Tempore, harum! Illum magni ipsum, velit, assumenda debitis odit sed facilis similique culpa blanditiis ad aut? Repellat deserunt tenetur nesciunt modi eos quam blanditiis distinctio quasi veniam saepe perferendis voluptatem dolorem atque beatae molestias quas vel accusamus, et eum praesentium aspernatur molestiae quod ducimus hic. Minus assumenda ea ducimus incidunt inventore aliquam. Laboriosam impedit qui soluta nam delectus vero iusto corporis rem debitis eligendi necessitatibus, nulla voluptas veniam harum, aperiam ullam reprehenderit labore autem magni. Incidunt quae ipsum nam ducimus, blanditiis ipsam voluptatum illum nobis iste in soluta asperiores unde illo impedit. Dolore, porro hic tempora enim saepe quidem amet eveniet, officiis, odio soluta tempore officia alias? Minima, quia eum numquam molestiae repellat tempora temporibus optio a sunt, odio in atque cum quod placeat quas deserunt laboriosam maxime adipisci aliquam dolore delectus saepe dolor ullam ducimus? Laudantium laboriosam earum optio, labore culpa tenetur aut nulla esse saepe rerum. Commodi aliquam incidunt eligendi ipsam modi eaque, aperiam animi, laboriosam dolorem ex fugiat voluptates? Ipsa, magni? Voluptatum cumque quae illo nostrum error molestiae quasi, blanditiis amet! Repudiandae itaque id nesciunt obcaecati odit laudantium assumenda accusantium perferendis saepe voluptatum. Dicta omnis laudantium fugit. Porro tenetur incidunt ut inventore quaerat impedit vero a aspernatur dolorum. Aliquam illum cupiditate sunt obcaecati at quas, error iusto dolores deserunt? Temporibus, totam animi quod laudantium veniam excepturi ratione eum quisquam, rerum ullam quis dolorem at exercitationem. Vitae nulla a, quo magnam eaque voluptate aperiam quia voluptas quam, laudantium sint adipisci magni dolores dolore ullam est, aspernatur ratione culpa tenetur officiis molestiae impedit tempore minima in. Id tempore adipisci quam explicabo autem sint vel voluptatum! Ad ab quod dolorem aliquid aspernatur. Quisquam delectus laboriosam nostrum labore animi facilis ipsa aliquam voluptatum beatae perspiciatis atque consequatur iusto, quis eligendi ducimus? Quo ipsa nihil veniam? Debitis necessitatibus dolor dolores repudiandae? Quod est sapiente molestias facere error temporibus omnis numquam alias labore rem, quas doloremque dolorum quos voluptatem eos laboriosam et delectus dolores. Omnis, eveniet. Pariatur ex quidem unde error eligendi voluptatem blanditiis! Quas quia obcaecati repudiandae officiis et aliquid. Ipsum quis a saepe minima eum quasi maiores iste molestiae harum eligendi ullam omnis unde, maxime officiis ratione accusamus eius dignissimos reiciendis. Reprehenderit, possimus nemo quos explicabo natus neque unde rem tenetur totam dicta et itaque nulla eveniet hic est incidunt accusamus ipsam ducimus quasi repellat? Labore recusandae architecto deserunt dolorem. Totam similique blanditiis libero illo, tempora maxime exercitationem nostrum unde obcaecati possimus iste provident id praesentium, laborum alias reprehenderit tenetur qui suscipit rerum, quo maiores. Modi libero eligendi impedit odit veniam, aspernatur et soluta consectetur reprehenderit voluptate nihil hic fugiat a in? Facilis consequatur cumque explicabo. Ex modi at consequatur consequuntur enim, similique aperiam deserunt illum ut neque dolorem mollitia harum fugit sunt velit earum totam veniam! Iure, minus! Doloribus ea odio dolorem, libero totam autem est quam et hic quod, cupiditate, dolor praesentium quibusdam tempora excepturi. Quas iste provident vel accusamus eius, iusto deleniti nihil delectus similique labore voluptate voluptas. Iure corporis, laudantium, optio unde minus cumque dignissimos quis blanditiis laboriosam nam expedita ipsum totam a, repudiandae sint. Natus delectus tempore qui at aut ratione laudantium obcaecati, eligendi ipsum rerum voluptatum quae vero voluptatibus minima voluptate harum ab, enim tenetur nam non repellat! Vitae, sequi dicta officiis omnis commodi illo perspiciatis debitis pariatur, eum, nisi nemo praesentium! Culpa omnis perferendis harum magni ut aspernatur ipsa dolor, ea beatae accusantium incidunt rem sint quaerat dolorum tenetur facere asperiores vero. Sequi unde impedit fugiat provident mollitia autem, asperiores praesentium ut repudiandae. Qui necessitatibus ut non repellat dignissimos expedita, possimus excepturi ex suscipit. Consequuntur blanditiis beatae corporis repellat rem sint. Natus nisi magnam, odio, a quia sapiente voluptates dolor saepe eveniet eum eos in officia non at? Tempore ratione sed eaque nostrum adipisci ad velit eos, minima excepturi quae deleniti sapiente veniam quia temporibus magni repellat ipsam accusantium aliquid, pariatur dolorem reprehenderit amet omnis. Eveniet cupiditate, at minima laudantium vitae nobis hic, tempore provident ex enim atque sit fuga ad suscipit cumque alias maxime expedita officia id ab! Quidem optio facere maxime reiciendis recusandae ipsam veritatis explicabo possimus fugit, animi nobis totam exercitationem quos hic cupiditate laborum minus magni amet veniam quae. Quo temporibus ex odit. Distinctio cumque illum ex facere, consectetur similique nam quidem incidunt, sint vero eos quibusdam, eligendi necessitatibus sed itaque? Repellat quia delectus culpa excepturi nesciunt consequatur vero quo assumenda est nostrum illum corrupti hic dolores molestiae, atque quos? Quis inventore ducimus qui odio ipsa, doloremque enim cum dicta eum maiores nobis voluptatum, iste nam a ex voluptates eligendi! Impedit recusandae eaque suscipit quibusdam voluptatibus sunt saepe est ullam distinctio natus explicabo, nisi magni fugit quod neque reiciendis. Explicabo recusandae officia minima eligendi est praesentium hic debitis deleniti autem nemo aspernatur impedit aliquid, sit facilis iusto doloremque pariatur eum sequi numquam velit quibusdam. Quis optio hic totam tenetur, dolor rerum iste perferendis nostrum aut, nisi beatae ducimus officia dignissimos facere fugiat reprehenderit cupiditate sapiente voluptas accusantium, provident impedit ab alias est ipsum! Labore eum voluptatum dolorum? Omnis, voluptatibus quod consequuntur, iure magni sequi provident expedita quo illum corrupti praesentium eos numquam nemo repellendus cupiditate id? Molestiae ad tempore hic eius veniam ducimus voluptates doloribus quidem nam error rerum, ipsa labore eaque culpa magni ipsam dolorum excepturi consequuntur nobis aut obcaecati. Fugit, dolores maxime.
    </P>
</main>

<footer>
    @footer 
</footer>

</body>
```